# Laravel Lumen Query Return Wrong Timestamp Time

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I Have my Laravel Lumen App on Ubuntu server and I changed the server time zone and my app saves the created_at, update_at successfully with the right time zone, Now when I fetch some tables data I noticed that the results time is not the same as in the Data base.

For example :

- created_at in database = `2020-08-03 13:52:35`
- created_at in query result = `2020-08-03 10:52:35`

Update as per requested, Below is my query

```
 public function Outbox($id){
            
        $orders = DB::table('order_details as o')
                    ->join('user_profile as a','o.reciever_id','=','a.id')
                    ->join('regions as r','a.province','=','r.province')
                    ->where('o.sender_id' ,'=', $id)
                    ->select('a.bid','r.ar_name as province','o.order_bar','o.price','o.delivery_cost','o.description','o.type','o.dropoff_time as time','o.status','o.visual_status','o.created_at')
                    ->orderBy('o.created_at','desc')
                    ->get();
        if(count($orders) > 0){
                return response()->json(['status_code'=>1000,'data'=>$orders , 'message'=>null],200);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status_code'=>2000,'data'=>null , 'message'=>null],200);
            }
    }
```

What is the issue here ??

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: check timezone of server 

and laravel application in "<root>/config/app.php"

Comment: Lumen don't have config file

Answer (score 0):

In your `bootstrap/app.php` check your timezone in

```
date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));
```

and don't forget to add `APP_TIMEZONE` in your `.env` file

**Updated**

if you didn't find that line in `bootstrap/app.php` add it after bootstraping environment variables like

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__)
))->bootstrap();

date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));
```

and in `.env` add

```
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
```

Comment: there is no such timezone line in the app.php?

Comment: What version of Lumen you are using ?

Comment: Lumen (5.8.12).

Comment: Still the same result, nothing changed

Comment: OK, share your query with us so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219179/discussion-between-mahmoud-abdelgawad-and-ali-adil).

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to find out, that in Lumen you have to add to your `.env` file e.g.:

`DB_TIMEZONE="Europe/Warsaw"`

and this should solve the problem.

https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/8.x/config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

i've tried set the timezones in app.php and .env file. But nothing work. what works for me is, if you have the access to the database, you can change the timestamp datatype into datetime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).